# getting the owner's name from a SOQL query

Tags: soql, query, salesforce-id

Is there a way to get the Name from the OwnerId and Account__r.OwnerId in this query?

**Select Id, Name, OwnerId,Account__r.Name, Account__r.OwnerId from Sede_BU__C WHERE RecordtypeId = '01224000000B3JL'**

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the name of the owner using `Owner` as the name of the relationship between the objects.

```
Owner.Name, Account__r.Owner.Name
```

Comment: the query gets through, but as a result i see :  [object Object]  .

Comment: It sounds like you are doing the query in javascript and what you are seeing is the `toString()` method is being applied to the object with the query results. When you are using the object, make sure the object isn't getting converted to a string. For example, if you are just logging the value, instead of logging results with a plus sign `console.log("result" + result)`, use a comma instead: `console.log("result",result)`

Comment: no problem‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍