# Soql with multiple lookups on same object

Tags: soql, sobject, lookup-field

I am gathering data from the LiveChatTranscript and there are multiple references to user as lookup fields. How do I pick which property I want to use as my reference to user?

**LiveChatTranscript properties**

```
LastModifiedById Lookup(User)
CreatedById Lookup(User)
OwnerId Lookup(User,Group)
```

**query**

```
-webroot-/query/?q=select chatkey, caseid, status,requesttime, starttime, endtime,endedby,name,ReferrerUri,platform,location, waittime,body,supervisortranscriptbody, case.description, ownerid,***ownerid.user.alias??*** from livechattranscript where chatkey = '12345'
```

Do I just need to do 2 queries? One to get the chat data and one to get the owner data?

Comment: 1 query will suffice as owner data is lookup from LiveChatTranscript; OwnerId = `The ID of the operator who participated in the chat last; for missed chats, this is a system user.`; see also [soql and owner relationship answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169305/getting-the-owners-name-from-a-soql-query)

Comment: PERFECT! General question, how would I know to use "owner" instead of "user" since user is the lookup definition?

Comment: User is the target object of the lookup, Owner is the name of the relationship  - please refer to [Soql Relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm?search_text=relationship) to gain an understanding of the distinction